Blowfish flagging my newly deploy program transactions
Im a new Solana dev that has been developing a Telegram game built on Solana for the past 11 months. I recently migrated all my infrastructure from Devnet, where everything worked perfectly, to Mainnet.
My testers report, and ive experienced it myself, that blowfish shows up to THREE warnings that my game transaction is Malicious/Harmful in the Phantom Wallet.
Users would have to navigate past 3 separate warnings essentially telling them to turn back and not approve the game transaction.
Some context, my telegram game requires just ONE transaction from users to be able to play the game.
Users must approve/sign 1 transaction to link their Solana Address to their Telegram User ID, which allows the Telegram bot to spend the games native SPL token on the users behalf. That is all!
I reached out to Blowfish and this was their reply

Hello,
Thank you for contacting us! We will review your request shortly and let you know if any further information is needed. For reference, your ticket number is (2153).
To expedite the review process, please consider doing the following:

Please send us as much information as possible regarding your project and team, to include social media handles, Github, developer profiles, etc. These things will drastically increase the speed at which we're able to process your application.

If you are new in the space or an anonymous dev team, you may choose to have someone established in the developer community reach out to us (via email or @blowfishxyz on Twitter) to vouch for you. Similarly, if you do not have a lengthy history on social media channels or GitHub, we would recommend asking a well-known dev friend if they will consider speaking to us on your behalf.


Best,
Blowfish

I sent them all my project info and my own personal twitter account. Is this seriously how they verify projects are not scams instead of just looking at the contract themselves to ensure they are not scams?
I have 0 faith they will do the right thing and remove these warnings from my dapp.
Ive attached some screenshots of what a user would see thanks to blowfish.
How can I move forward? Have I wasted my time developing on Solana?



Also I have this issue. I need a known solana developer help me to blowfish add my webapp to whitelist. although I think blowfish project can harmful for freedom and solana

Are you asking users to sign a durable nonce?
